# Not seeing staticmap.png in Phonegap

Tags: android, image, cordova

Got Phonegap working, but not seeing the staticmap.png image for "your current location"

```
    <div id="map" class="view">
      <div class="map_image">
          <img id="static_map" src="assets/img/staticmap.png">
      </div>
      <p>This is where you are</p>
```

I do have the staticmap.png as assets/img/staticmap.png.
Any idea why it's not showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap's base is the assets/www directory.  Move img to www and then

```
  <img id="static_map" src="img/staticmap.png">
```